# SwiftUI VStack cell onTap acting strange

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-ontapgesture, lazyvstack

I have a bunch of cells in a vertical scroll view, but am seeing some weird behavior from the `onTapGesture` and `fullScreenCover` for those cells. When I click on a cell, it registers the correct cell in `onTapGesture` but presents the wrong object, in the `fullScreenCover` it looks like it's being executed many times, and presenting the wrong object. Not sure why this is happening, anyone have any insight on what the issue could be?

Here are the print statements from clicking 1 cell:

```
TAP HERE: 1935
FULL SCREEN: 1942
FULL SCREEN: 1940
FULL SCREEN: 1935
FULL SCREEN: 1934
```

```
    struct TakesList: View {
        
        @ObservedObject var viewModel: TakesListViewModel
        @State private var isPresented = false
        
        var body: some View {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(viewModel.takes, id: \.self) { take in
                        ListTakeCell(presenter: TakeCellViewModel(take: take))
                            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                            .padding(.vertical, 6)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                let _ = print("TAP HERE: \(take.id)")
                                UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light).impactOccurred()
                                isPresented = true
                            }
                            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented, onDismiss: nil, content: {
                                let _ = print("FULL SCREEN: \(take.id)")
                                SingleTakeView(take: take)
                                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
                            })
                            
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use instead `fullScreenCover(item` like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65480211/12299030

Comment: @Asperi it requires my struct conform to Identifiable, which I cannot do because ```id``` is already taken in that struct

Comment: @Asperi is there a way around that issue? I cannot changed ```id``` as it plays a role in a custom protocol I confirm my struct to

Comment: You use one isPresented for all rows, so once changed it activates all fullScreenCover modifiers. I don't see any problem with id, but actually you can use it as an item, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64664861/12299030. Anyway you have to move fullScreenCover out of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```swift
struct TakesList: View {
        
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: TakesListViewModel
    @State private var isPresented = false

    private var selectedTake: Take? = nil {
        didSet {
            guard selectedTake != nil else { return }
            isPresented = true
        }
    }
        
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(viewModel.takes, id: \.self) { take in
                    ListTakeCell(presenter: TakeCellViewModel(take: take))
                        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                        .padding(.vertical, 6)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            let _ = print("TAP HERE: \(take.id)")
                            UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light).impactOccurred()
                            selectedTake = take
                        }   
                }
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented, onDismiss: nil, content: {
                guard let take = selectedTake else { return }
                let _ = print("FULL SCREEN: \(take.id)")
                SingleTakeView(take: take)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Added the `selectedTake` property. This is kind of a workaround for not being able to use `fullScreenCover(item`. When the cell is tapped, you set the `selectedTake` property with the `take` that was tapped. Then a `didSet` gets triggered which checks to make sure `selectedTake` isn't `nil`. If it isn't, then it sets `isPresented` to `true`. The `fullScreenCover(isPresented` modifier is moved out of the list onto the `LazyVStack` which still gets triggered if `isPresented` becomes `true`. I haven't tested this, but it's an idea that could work.

Curious if this works for you. Cheers!